# Is it Possible common header/footer for all web pages using with static site generater

Tags: static-site, eleventy

We have worked on a static site. we have used the javascript client-side and HTML. I am a beginner to jam-stack and static site generators. we have common code for all pages i.e header and footer related code. How can I use common header/footer for all pages with using the static site generaters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer for *all* static site generators, but for Eleventy you would use a layout file. This is [documented](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/layouts/) well but here's an example.

First, ensure you've got an `_includes` folder, this is where Eleventy looks for layouts and includes by default. (You can change this.) Create a layout file using the template language of your choice, so for example: `main.liquid`:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
{{ content }}
</body>
</html>
```

In this template, the contents of your page will be in the `content` variable. To use this layout, in your regular markdown files, reference it in the front matter:

```html
---
layout: main
---

## Hello World

Im markdown!
```

This assumes you want a "wrapper" for your layout. You can also just create a file called `header.liquid` (or use the extension of the template language you prefer) and `footer.liquid` and then include them from your files.

Eleventy is *very* flexible and gives you a lot of options.